# PHP Url Relative and Absolute

Tags: php

I have this class:

```
class PageBuilder {
    public function GetHeader() {
        include(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/template/header.php');
    }
}
```

Which when called will insert the header file into my page. All is good.

```
$page_builder->GetHeader();
```

In the `header.php` is the top of the `HTML` file which includes a menu. My problem is,  depending on where the `PageBuilder` gets called from changes the menu link `URL`s.

How do I make sure they are always relative to the root folder.

`dirname(__FILE__)` doesn't work because it turns the `URL` into `file:///`, also I really don't want to append the entire `http://www.blahblah.com/blah` because if it is relative to the root it doesn't matter about any of that.

***EDIT***

So as someone posted you can use `$_SERVER['']` but which one is reliable, no doubt `PHP` will have put in some blinding caveats.

See I was thinking `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` .....

Going `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` for now .. result is fail.

Just prefixing with `/` resolves to the localhost root so my links are `localhost/admin/profile.php` rather than `localhost/TestApp/admin/profile.php`, Do I have to actually specify that it sits in folder named `TestApp`?

Comment: `__FILE__` will resolve to PageBuilder.php, so will not be relative. Have a look in `$_SERVER` - there's plenty of fully-qualified paths in there that you could use instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am reading your question correctly, but `dirname` should never be used on URLs, and in most cases you should not need to `include` HTTP references either. More to the point, your classes should not be available over the web either.

Comment: PHP is an object-oriented language, yes; I'm not sure what has prompted you to think otherwise. That's not really the issue here though. I'd advise that whatever language you are using, you get into a positive frame of mind with it, or you'll set yourself expectations to fail. So, give my suggestion a go, and let us know how you get on!

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: @No1 By "C#" you likely mean "C# *and the whole .NET framework*". The .NET framework may contain functions to deal with this already, but PHP is not .NET. PHP is only the language, just as C# is only the language. You can use any number of PHP frameworks and libraries which contain code to help with this.

Comment: @deceze again, assignment, I would use C# .NET MVC 4 etc etc or even Node Js with Express. But unfortunately, uni's will be uni's

Comment: And again, don't complain about PHP, but realise that PHP is closer to the bare metal than .NET is. You'd have the same problems in C# if you didn't have .NET with it.

Comment: The problem here is just not knowing PHP well enough - it would be the same with me and .net! PHP has its inconsistencies, but none that have affected this problem as far as I can tell.

Comment: @halfer I'm not sure what this means "your classes chould not be available over the web", if `PHP` is a server side script then it gets executed server side and what gets sent to the user is the `HTML` stream. Surely my classes aren't exposed client side?

Comment: @No1: they shouldn't be, but I understood from your question (perhaps misreading it) that you were trying to run `include('http://www.blahblah.com/classes/PageBuilder.inc')`. or something like that. I believe the `include` functions are able to read classes remotely, but it isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error with the help of @deceze I simply pass my `URL` through a routing class which prefixes the `URL` with '/TestApp/' this can be change easily if the project gets moved because the use of classes.

So I do:

```
<a href="<?php $url_routing->ParseUrl('admin/account/logout.php') ?>">Log Out </a>
```

Gets passed through:

```
public function ParseUrl($url) {
    return '/TestApp/' . $url;
}
```

It is hardly best practice, but there can't be best practices with a language that doesn't follow any itself.

Looking at @Anthony answer of using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` it does always give the `TestApp` folder. Needs more looking into but I will take that. I assume its relative to the server address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate between *local file paths* and *URLs* first and foremost. The two have nothing to do with one another.  PHP with its `__FILE__` and `dirname()` and related parts is dealing only with local file paths on the server's hard disk. URLs on the other hand are entirely arbitrary strings that *you* need to put together in a sensible way. There are an infinite ways how any one particular file may be referred to by a URL, it's up to you to bring order into this.

You *could* try to figure out which URL was requested using the various paths available in `$_SERVER` and construct relative URLs based on that. However, this is rather error prone and overly complicated. Rather you should be using root-relative URLs. I.e. instead of

```
foo/bar.html
```

which is relative to the URL the browser is currently on, you always use

```
/foo/bar.html
```

which always refers to the same URL regardless of what URL it's currently relative to.

If you need a prefix for all your URLs, I'd create a wrapper function which adds this as needed based on configuration or on automatically figuring out its own root URL based on `$_SERVER`.

Comment: I looked for a key in `$_SERVER` but none really give a good idea as to the root folder... I think I will go with adding the folder in before the `URL` making sure that it is prefixed with `/`